# TypeScript: How to get nested functions to union their types through a chain

Tags: typescript, higher-order-functions, union-types

What I'm trying to do is create a series of nested functions which can be chained together, and the final callback's arguments will be a union of the parents. Example of my failed attempt so far:

[TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKEC2wASBDAOwBMAbYKAHgBUA+OAXjgAo8oBzAZwC44qBKBnQBuEAJZEA3ACgpSFHADqomAAsAYhAgBBdhwZwA3nABmmnhxhRRBNnAC+UgMYQCFuAHdl6zfuoAaGiYVQlJyHgxsfGIySio4ADJFLw1tXRoBejoWXR44xKVVFJ1ODLpg6PJskulZZFQClQAhVmK9RiMAI1ZzS2tbB2dXeE9VZqhfKgCgkJjwrFwZ8moEpNGWtNLmVk5clYax1s3y0Kgqjj4auXqvAC1NVv0jAC8zOAsrG3snFzcRlTuIBMpsdZuh5lETst8rd7htBFscrw9jDUiV4SDKttzjUpKBILA4ERgMY8ABXEjDZKaJh-MY0lFMM6bAxSOBsuAAeg5cAAkh5CPAsQhAR1UFc4AADBpFXTItZQB7Q1QA1oSqR2Pia6RAA)

```
export type SomeHandler<T> = (args: T) => void;

type WithFooArgs = { foo: string }
const withFoo = <T,>(handler: SomeHandler<T & WithFooArgs>) => (args: T & WithFooArgs) => handler(args);

type WithBarArgs = { bar: string }
const withBar = <T,>(handler: SomeHandler<T & WithBarArgs>) => (args: T & WithBarArgs) => handler(args);

type WithZooArgs = { zoo: string }
const withZoo = <T,>(handler: SomeHandler<T & WithZooArgs>) => (args: T & WithZooArgs) => handler(args);


export default withFoo(withBar(withZoo((args) => {
    // I want args to be type `WithFooArgs & WithBarArgs & WithZooArgs`
})));
```

The goal is to have a bunch of these which I can chain together in different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to change the generics of `withZoo(..)` based upon the expressions around it which is not possible.  You could create a single generic that takes in these middleware-like callbacks then use the data from those callbacks to type a single callback function like the following:

```
export type SomeHandler<T> = (args: T) => void;

type WithFooArgs = { foo: string }
const withFoo = <T,>(handler: SomeHandler<T & WithFooArgs>) => (args: T & WithFooArgs) => handler(args);

type WithBarArgs = { bar: string }
const withBar = <T,>(handler: SomeHandler<T & WithBarArgs>) => (args: T & WithBarArgs) => handler(args);

type WithZooArgs = { zoo: string }
const withZoo = <T,>(handler: SomeHandler<T & WithZooArgs>) => (args: T & WithZooArgs) => handler(args);

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/10873797
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never;

function createHandler<Handler extends SomeHandler<any>>(handlers: Handler[], cb: (args: UnionToIntersection<Parameters<Parameters<Handler>[0]>[0]>) => void) {
    return (args: any) => {
        return cb(handlers.reduce((acc, cur) => cur(acc), args));
    };
}

export default createHandler([withFoo, withBar, withZoo], (args) => {
    console.log(args); // WithFooArgs & WithBarArgs & WithZooArgs
});
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKEC2wASBDAOwBMAbYKAHgBUA+OAXjgAo8oBzAZwC44qBKBnQBuEAJZEA3ACgpSFHADqomAAsAYhAgBBdhwZwA3nABmmnhxhRRBNnAC+UgMYQCFuAHdl6zfuoAaGiYVQlJyHgxsfGIySio4ADJFLw1tXRoBejoWXR44xKVVFJ1ODLpg6PJskulZZFQClQAhVmK9RiMAI1ZzS2tbB2dXeE9VZqhfKgCgkJjwrFwZ8moEpNGWtNLmVk5clYax1s3y0Kgqjj4auXqvAC1NVv0jAC8zOAsrG3snFzcRlTuIBMpsdZuh5lETst8rd7htBFscrw9jDUiV4SDKttzjUAPQ4uAqGAwMDcPEWPCOADWECE5GMJAg7gAdM5MDi8DiAKwABgAzAB2TkAJgAHAA2HEARm5Iv5AoAnPzavIAKoEUQuKgQACSBBg5A4wEcMA1BAoKrojCkcGYKrgoH1xD0hEQcAA-MxKTwVXxMiJxHAeARgLSoAIHcAncwmF64NZjOQ4NrfTR-UQBB7tYG4MHQzVjABXAjG01wRxQYB4fUQmIUGuJiNRiILCqUF00QIYqDcOD1qAAbQAun4yx0eGdverNTq9QajSaXBQAAqsPDYfXd5er9cGuuLKA0fvcweH4-peFpgQGa02uAVmAFqAEBE7OAuzbX29fu-AB9P0fTK2HBMhWRAFo4wBMCwjiOCOjiPps8GnBSjh8COWJ8BcN42nY0gODIUigJAsBwEQwDGHgBYkPA5aVtW+5MP2fwpCOfxjKxKLDi+5zwp+t6DBwEBkEyDJsGcFxwHiqzeKiejQmsUAPPJ-ywpwUh2FhQA)